# Most memory-efficient way to define hundreds of double constants

Tags: c, embedded

What is the most memory-efficient way to define hundreds of double (64-bit floating point) constants for use in an embedded C program? Please note this application is memory-constrained and I need to save as much RAM as possible.

It's an Atmel AVR with 2048B RAM clocked @ 8MHz. 32K Flash.

Comment: Efficient in what? Memory, speed, compilation simplicity?

Comment: In terms of source code or what? If you have the full list of the constants, it's may be possible to construct a compression scheme.

Comment: I clarified the original question - I'm trying to minimize memory usage. Compression is not a viable option.

Comment: If compression is not an option, how are you supposed to consume less than 64*N bits in total?

Comment: What I'm trying to avoid is doing it like this: `double hey = 12.252323245` as a global variable so that 64*N bits are NOT loaded into memory at the same time. I've considered doing `#define hey 12.252323245` so that items are only loaded into memory when needed in a calculation rather than having them there all the time.

Comment: For your purpose `#define` works quite well, as does `const double hey=12.3;` An optimizing compiler should be able to remove all the unneeded constants from the binary.

Comment: :) "loaded into memory when needed" You are just choosing between where to put them -- in code or data section. Your program will *naturally* use every constant at least once, so they all will be in code section, which is not less, but probably more than single record per constant in data section. But then code will reference to them, and this will add one pointer per constant. Not sure what is more 'efficient', but this is subject to heavy testing and probably not for asking on SO.

Comment: I will also point out that the code is heavily scoped, so when used they should not, according to my understanding, persist in memory when the scope is left. Thoughts?

Comment: An optimizing compiler will also perform constant folding, replacing e.g. `3.14 / 3.14` with `1.0`, eliminating completely some constants, but introducing others.

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen - `doesn't const double hey=12.3` ALWAYS load the value into memory - and since these exist at a global scope it means they'll always be there? I'm thinking this vs. using #defines wherever possible - shouldn't the #defines only load the values into memory when they're needed if the code is scoped and unload them when the scope is left?

Comment: Scoping does not require the constant to be loaded to the stack at the point of introduction in the source code. Instead the constants probably reside in a separate segment, or they are embedded in the opcodes -- which ever is more size-optimal as seen by the compiler.

Comment: Compiler can implement `const double hey=12.3;` without allocating any memory to it. Only taking a reference `double *f = &variable;` mandates the variable to be located in memory. Even then the memory can be RAM or ROM.

Comment: What type of cpu you use, how much RAM/ROM you have, how many floats you need, how do you work with them, how they are created?

Comment: Thanks @jeb :-) It's an Atmel AVR with 2048B RAM clocked @ 8MHz. 32K Flash. Not much room for copious variables. I need more room for heap/stack variables.

Answer (score 2):

In large part, the way to have constants not use memory is to store them in a file and read them as needed.

If you cannot do that, then the constants must form part of the program, and they will occupy memory one way or another, either in a data segment or as immediates in instructions.

If full precision is not needed, you may be able to reduce the data to `float` instead of `double`.

A few processor architectures provide for encoding simple floating-point constants in instructions. If you are targeting such a processor, you should study its documentation to learn what constants are supported. This is unlikely to be useful for general data.

If the data has some pattern, you may be able to use that to generate parts as needed as run-time. (This includes various forms of compression and decompression, which depend on patterns in data.) Obviously, this depends on the nature of the data, which you have not included in your question.

Another possibility that should be considered is whether your program needs all the raw data it uses or whether some portion of the work can be performed in advance to reduce the data needed.

Otherwise, by and large, data is data, and it takes the space it takes.

Comment: When really low on memory, one can design and emulate an instruction set of a special purpose processor, that loads floating point constants efficiently e.g. from a PATRICIA tree -- and hope that the implementation pays off.

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen: (a) A tree would only be a way of organizing data, not of compressing it. There is no reason to expect it would save space. (b) There is no sense in emulating some processor to load data unless you mean to use it to generate the data, somehow taking advantage of patterns in it. Then this is simply compression-decompression, which is already mentioned in my answer.

Comment: Given the embedded nature of the problem, this might be a system where the "file" solution may look more like using the appropriate compiler and linker flags to keep the constant in flash, specifically, to avoid RAM copies initialized from flash storage and then never altered.  Many toolchains will place constant variables in RAM by default, as data access to program (flash) space on MCU's tends to challenge the pipeline and thus be slow, but where a compact memory footprint is preferred over speed, it can be useful to specifically instruct the toolchain to leave it in flash.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: That would make sense. The OP would have to provide more details about their system. Either static or automatic objects could have their initial values stored in flash memory and start to consume space in RAM only when they are used in expressions. So the real problem might be to minimize the working memory of the program.

Answer (score 2):

Expecting you use the AVRStudio:
When you want to place variables to flash only, you could use

```
#include <avr/pgmspace.h>
const char myString[] PROGMEM = "AT\r";
const float myFloat PROGMEM = 3.1415926535f;
```

Some more infos about placing and reading (for AVR) can be found at 
[Data in Program Space](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/pgmspace.html)

There doesn't exists a general solution, it depends on the platform(von Neumann or Harvard) and toolchain.

Some compilers uses
`__attribute__(section(".myFlashSection"))`
some others uses pragmas like
`#pragma SET_CONST_PAGE(ConstArea)`.

And there are some strange ones like

```
#pragma define_section flash_table ".myFlashTable.text" RW
#pragma section flash_table begin
```

And others moves always the const data to a flash section.

Comment: I'm aware of the PROGMEM macro and have used it before with strings so they aren't allocated in memory until needed. This macro is included in avrlibc and - to my understanding - only works with AVR chips. Say I'm using and ARM chip and want to do the same thing - do you know of a method to accomplish this/is this even the right approach at all? I know that accessing PROGMEM data from flash comes with a performance hit since there is a much higher access time vs RAM. Any idea on what the latency is? This is performance-critical code that uses all these doubles.

Answer (score 1):

Declare it as `const double array_name[] = { ... };` and expect the linker to store it on flash only.

Be aware you must check the map file to be sure no copy has been made to the ram.